# Is it possible to decrypt multiple keys?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have several roles in the application.

`1) Users
2) Merchants
3) Admin`

Each role has its own secret key.

`1) keysUser
2) keysMerchant
3) keysAdmin`

I store the keys in the configuration file

```
...
    keysUser: {
        secret: '/...=',
        expires: '2 days'
    },
    keysMerchant: {
        secret: '/..=',
        expires: '2 days'
    },
    keysAdmin: {
        secret: '/...=',
        expires: '2 days'
    },
...
```

If three roles can add a product, then how to decrypt the token, if, for example, the user added or the seller.

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    try {
        jwt.verify(
            req.headers.token,
                config.'{keysAdmin?, keysMerchant?, keysAdmin? How to write a condition for three roles}'.secret,
                (err, decoded) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            name: "TokenExpiredError",
                            message: "jwt expired"
                        });
                    }
                ....
```

How to make that which token (seller, user, administrator) come and decrypt?

How can I determine that all three roles could add a product, and only the administration and the seller could delete it?

Comment: The token should contain all three scopes - you don't give three tokens for one user to define the scope, that's not how you're supposed to work with JWTs. *citation needed

Comment: I would rather consider user-roles and write some guards for those specific roles..

Comment: @maio290 Can be more ?